# JHipster Registry cannot get logfile

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-cloud-config, jhipster-registry

I Have a JHipster monolith application running successfully along with JHipster Registry. Everything is fine, I can see my application instance and all metrics.

But I get the following hint under the tab Administration/Logs:

```
No available logfile. 
Please check:
 - if the microservice is up
 - these properties are set: 
     - logging.path
     - logging.file (to avoid using the same spring.log)

See:
 - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html
 - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html
```

And a **404 Status response** for `/management/logfile`

As already mentioned the service is running and in `application-*.yml` logging is set to

```
logging.file: /opt/tomcat/logs/shorty.log
```

The read permission for this file is shared by everyone.
Why I can't see the contents of the log file? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my `Spring Cloud Config` was wrong. I had the additional `logging.path` property set.

But this seems not necessary with the default configuration. After removing this in `application.yaml` for JHipster Registry everything worked like a charm.